# Color Literal gives different colors than UIColor init (I can't compare them)

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I am creating colors in two ways in my codebase: using color literals and with `UIColor(red:green:blue:)` initializer. Those colors look the same but when I try to compare them, they have slightly different components.

To have a handy init that accepts integers instead of floating numbers I have an extension:

```
extension UIColor {

    convenience init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int) {
        self.init(red: CGFloat(red)/255.0, green: CGFloat(green)/255.0, blue: CGFloat(blue)/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

My test fails when I try to test if colors are the same:

```
func testColorComparision() {
    let literalColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.5764705882, blue: 0, alpha: 1) // This was a picked-up color "tangerine" rgb(255,147,0)
    let rgbColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 147, blue: 0)
    XCTAssertEqual(literalColor, rgbColor) // Colors are not the same!
}
```

Comment: 0.5764705882 * 255 = 146,999999991 may be you should ceil the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had a mistake in my extension code. `UIColor(red:green:blue:)` accepts CGFloats but those CGFloats should be numbers before 64-bit era. CGFloat is represented in float in 32-bit architectures but as double in 64-bit architectures. However, components of UIColors are 32-bit numbers. I modified my extension:

```
extension UIColor {

    convenience init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int) {
        self.init(red: CGFloat(Float(red)/255.0), green: CGFloat(Float(green)/255.0), blue: CGFloat(Float(blue)/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

And the test passed. The first cast is to have a number as Float, the second one is to get CGFloat number accepted by the init.